# How do I ignore a library from the affected command on a NX Monorepo? Or just

Tags: angular, nestjs, monorepo, nx-workspace, nxwl

I am working on an Angular/Nestjs monorepo with several little libraries. Everything works as expected but for one case.

There are two root libraries that are just used on tests (unit, and integration). One is an Angular Lib, other a NestJS Lib.

Those libs contain helper functions that generate objects of different interfaces, entities, etc.

I want to ignore changes on that Lib because most changes are just to add new helper functions. (When the old functions are changed, the "real" libraries that import those the interfaces will be marked as affected anyway) .

I want to prevent that `LibraryA`, who imports functions from `TestingLibrary` gets marked as `affected` when a developer adds a new function there to test `LibraryB`.

Can this be done?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? https://nx.dev/using-nx/affected#ignoring-files-from-affected-commands

Comment: This sounds about right. I have to test it.

Comment: @AllanJuan sadly this breaks `workspace-lint` saying that `The angular.json file is out of sync`